# python classification for a polyA.fa dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have a file.fa contains two tuples: a sequence of DNA and a class for that DNA.

I want to train this file in python and keras library for classification. 
What is the best way to read and preprocess data in python? Does chainging the format of the file will help for better reading and classifying?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to one-hot encode each base of each sequence, so A, C, T, G becomes [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]. An input instance is therefore a vector with 4X as many numbers as bases, with only one out of every four numbers being non-zero.

The classes that you use for answers will likely be one-hot encoded as well. Since the position of the bases in the sequence matters you will probably get best results with a convolutional neural network.

Answer (score -1):

A fasta file can be treated basically the same as a txt file:

```
seqs = []

# Load in the fasta, line by line
with open('fasta_file.fa') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        seqs.append(line.strip())

# Merge the lines / first line is title typically, starting with >
dna_seq = {}
dna_seq[seqs.pop(0).strip('>')] = ''.join(seqs)
```